# Aggregation relationship in class diagram?

Tags: java, oop, uml, class-diagram

I want to ask a question about aggregation relationship in the world of object oriented programming.

Now i have a class that composed of 2 classes.

We know in aggregation relationship that the main class has a reference to the aggregate class as an attribute

But the main class doesn't contain any attributes or methods except the aggregate classes.

Is this correct in the world of object oriented programming

for example:

main class called knight:

the others are horse and sword.

So the knight class are composed of horse and sword.

this is an aggregation relationship...

```
public class knight{
private horse h;
private sword s;

// no others attributes and methods
}
```

my question: is leaving the class knight without any attributes and methods as above correct ???

Comment: Why downvote? It is a correct question, exactly asked. +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is correct, but useless.

You have forgotten, that you have to expose somehow the knight's properties. Fields or some methods working with them should be public. Or your knight is not a knight, but a hermit :-)

For example:

```
public boolean putSwordOn(Sword sword){}; //sets current sword
public boolean putSwordInSheath(){};  // uses sword
public boolean pullSwordOut(){};      // uses sword
public boolean attack(Creature target){};   // uses sword
public void kissSwordAndSwearToServe(Knight senior); // uses sword
public boolean climbHorse(Horse horse){};   // sets current horse
public boolean gallop(Point direction){};   // uses horse
```

Also, you have a problem in terminology. Such connection (has a) is shown by **`association`**. And that is shown on the class diagram by a solid line, probably with points or a diamond or an arrowhead. An **`association`** has some **`aggregation`**. It is about how many instances of that type belong to that field and how do they belong. **`aggregation`** can be **`composition`**, **`shared`** or **`none`**. We can say that this **`association`** has **`aggregation`** of type **`none`**, but to name "aggregation" something, that has **`none`** aggregation is obviously incorrect. So, you are talking about **`association`** relationship.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer, but i have another question. you say that it's correct but useless. now if this class is become useless forever while writing my code. you think this is correct too ? ... now i want to access horse and sword classes only from the main class(knight) ... is making sword and horse abstract a good idea for this???

Comment: 1. You have all rights to make a useless class. It can be useful for training and demonstration its problems. 2. As for use abstract classes for fields, yes, it is very frequent and modern way. You DECLARE them as something most common - as some interface or abstract class, but you CREATE/CONSTRUCT them as some instantiable class. `List list=new ArrayList() `.  I don't think Sword and Horse should be abstract classes. But you can make abstract classes Weapon and Steed.

Comment: so you think better use methods with the main class to make it useful?

Comment: 1. Please, edit your post and change aggregations for associations. Keep your question free of unnecessary errors. 2. If your class does something, you can make it do do it only by calling its functions. Or you can create public inner class, expose ITS functions and reach the outer class from within. It is possible, but very dirty.  Even if your class is for illustration only, your teacher will ask: how you want to use it? The class historically appeared as set of fields and methods, and a class without methods is quite a special thing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, why wouldn't it?

There's absolutely no reason why that would not be correct.